# How to tackle the ODE $f'(\lambda x) = f'(x)\sin(x) + f(x)\cos(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How can I tackle the problem of finding $f$ such that, for every
>   $\lambda >0$,
>   $$ f'(\lambda x) = f'(x)\sin(x) + f(x)\cos(x) \text{ ?}$$

The only thing I noticed is that it's equivalent to find $f$ such that $\forall \lambda >0$,

$$\frac{f(\lambda x)}{\lambda} = f(x)\sin(x). $$

In fact, I was trying to find a real function $f$ with $f(\lambda x)/f(x)\sim \lambda \sin(x)$ as $x\to +\infty$, and all I got was this "strange looking" ODE (to me, for I think I never saw anything like this before). Any tips on how to deal with this kind of equation?

Comment: "Strange looking" is a subjective and not informative comment. Please edit your title to a more appropriate one.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y>0$. Taking $\lambda = 1$ we have
$$ f'(x) = f'(x) \cos(x) + f(x) \sin(x)$$
also there exists $\hat \lambda$ such that $y = \hat \lambda x$ so
$$f'(y) = f'(\hat\lambda x) = f'(x) \cos(x) + f(x) \sin(x) = f'(x)$$
so $f'$ is constant which implies that $f$ is linear. Its easy to prove that the only linear function that satisfies the equation is the null function.

Comment: Well, that was easier than I thought. I think I need to study a little bit more about ODEs haha. Thanks!